# rails column not found for association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attributes

I have a menu that has_many daily_items and a daily_item belongs_to an item. I want to order the daily_items of a menu based on an attribute of their items. I've tried 
`the_menu.daily_items.order("item.attr")`
but I get an error saying that `item.attr` is not a column of `daily_item`. While I know this is true, why does it not look up the reference to `item` according to the `daily_item.item_id` and then look up `attr`? I thought that was the point of associations, that we could just so something like `daily_item.item.attr`. How can I sort based on an attribute of item?

Comment: are you literally using "attr" as field or attribute name?

Comment: no I wasn't lol the answer was the response below though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have 2 problems:
1. you need to include the item
2. you are prividing a table name in the sort so it should be plural

Something like:

```
the_menu.daily_items.include(:item).order("items.attr")
```

should work